# what is the method to find startings and endings dates of an event with google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, gcal

I'm trying to get data from an event using google-api-php-client. Particulary the starting and ending date of the event.

I have tried

```
foreach ($event->when as $when) { ...
```

but nothing.

Impossible to find the documentation of google-api-php-client with all the methods.
Does somebody has a link?

Comment: this is Google Calendar correct?

Comment: Yes this is google calendar

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of requesting just a set of events based upon a time frame.  Your best bet is to just get them all then loop though them yourself.  [ListEvents](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');
```

**Note** There is a q option for searching but I don't think it works for dates.   I would have to test it

> Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in any
>   field, except for extended properties. Optional.

Most of the methods have php code in the documentation [Google Calendar API Refrence](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way :

```
$start = $event->getStart()->dateTime ;
$end   =  $event->getEnd()->dateTime ;
```

But I havent found the documentation relative to theses metods